# Programmatically Configure aws-iot button

Tags: react-native, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-iot

i'm trying to create an RN APP and i want to know if there is any way to programatically configure AWS IOT button?.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/configure-iot.html

App is already connecting to **Button ConfigureMe - XXX** network.
The next step is configuring the button, i want to configure the button without the user opening the browser to 192.168.0.1/index.html

[image]

i want to build some ajax request to **192.168.0.1/configure** passing the form data it needs.

`wifi_ssid
wifi_password
aws_iot_certificate
aws_iot_private_key
endpoint_region
endpoint_subdomain`

**i can see the action endpoint from network console `192.168.0.1/configure`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with a curl command in Linux. First you need the body of `multipart/form-data`. You could get it from the browser console after you click Configure button. Once you have the body, just run this, where $BOUNDARY is from the body text.

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=$BOUNDARY" \
  -F file=@body.txt \
  http://192.168.0.1/configure
```

I'm still trying to make it work with Powershell via Invoke-RestMethod but still no luck